# Developer oriented Windows command shell with bookmarks?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, shell

I'm looking for a command shell in Windows 7 ala Powershell that allows me to have bookmarks and such, so I can start a shell in a specific directory, remember command history, have completion for more than just pathnames.

Is there anything that works on Windows 7 64-bit natively?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one... http://jpsoft.com/index.html. I have not used it but it looks like it is what you want.

[image]

I know there is another one out there similar to this one but it is like $700.

Comment: Thanks, looks nice but I would prefer freeware, not necessarily open source. Might be worth a look, but I won't be using this to a level that justifies such expenditure.

Comment: http://alternativeto.net/software/take-command/ look at that list... Console & PowerCMD look decent one is free the other is $30